# Failed to Fetch from Electron: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, electron

I have some trouble with using XHR in Electron. In my MacOS, it worked perfectly, but tested from another MacOS, fetch fails with:

> net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Tested with Windows 10 worked fine, but it only happens with other MacOS laptops. I goggled that error but nothing useful found.

Getting data via XHR with chrome on another MacOS was worked, but only electron fails with same error. I tested with just type fetch directly in console:

`fetch('http://api.example.com')`

it still fails. Looks like it only happens on Electron and I'm stuck here. Any advice will very helpful to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Electron's Certificate Transparency Issue**

Depending on your version of Electron, this could be related to [the recent Certificate Transparency issues that affected Electron's underlying Chrome library](http://electron.atom.io/blog/2016/12/09/certificate-transparency-fix).

The issue itself could cause certain certificates such as Symantec, GeoTrust, and Thawte to be incorrectly rejected, and thus resulting in Electron not serving your expected content after a given period of time.

You may want to ensure that you are running at least Electron 1.4.12, which is expected to have resolved the issue.